# "sites-available" and "default" missing in nginx installation path

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, gunicorn, amazon-linux

So I was trying to deploy my `python-flask app` on `AWS`. I have rented the server and have setup everything. I was using [this](https://medium.com/techfront/step-by-step-visual-guide-on-deploying-a-flask-application-on-aws-ec2-8e3e8b82c4f7) to do my work of deploying application on AWS server. Up until Step 6 everything was perfect but then as it said in Step 6, I need to add some configurations in `default` file inside `sites-available` folder in `nginx directory`, but in my case I don't have any `sites-available` folder, I am using `Amazon Linux AMI`. Can anyone tell me where to add those configurations mentioned in Step 6 or how to create that default file. I even tried to reinstall `nginx` but the problem doesn't solve, no `sites-available` folder exists.

Answer (score 4):

Look for `include` statements in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to find out which files and directories are scanned for configuration snippets. There might be something like this:

```
http {
  ...
  include sites-available/*;  # import any file from /etc/nginx/sites-available
  ...
  include conf.d/*.conf;  # import '*.conf' files from /etc/nginx/conf.d
  ...
}
```

You can use this to find out which directory is used or just create your own one.

Comment: There was the following line in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`: `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` in version `1.18.0 (Ubuntu)` but no such in `1.21.6`. No such in original sources: https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/branches/stable-1.18/conf/nginx.conf or http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nginx/nginx_1.18.0.orig.tar.gz . However. the line exists in Debian `nginx-core 1.18.0` repository package version: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nginx/nginx_1.18.0-0ubuntu1.3.debian.tar.xz in `./debian/conf/nginx.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Ubuntu linux next time, personally think it is way easier to use.

So `sites-available` folder is in `/etc/nginx/`. You can do:

`sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, if password required, enter root user password.

Then input following code:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        # root   html;
        # index  index.html;
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_redirect  off;
        
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    }
```

Then `:wq`

Remember to change the PORT if you're not running flask on 5000.

Then do `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

Then do `sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Check if `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` is inside `http{...}` and is not commented.

Then `:q` to quit.

Then do `sudo nginx -s reload` if your nginx is running, or do `sudo systemctl start nginx` if it is not running.

Then open http://yourWebsite.

---

For more details for you to understand nginx:

This is not necessary:

```
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
```

You can change the `default` to any other name you want.

Folder `sites-available` is for the different sites on the server.

Folder `sites-enabled` is for the shortcuts of files in `sites-available`.

files in `sites-available` will be imported through `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` into `nginx.conf`.

Comment: There's no sites-enabled folder as well, do I need to add something, since the medium article doesn't say anything about that file

Comment: If `sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default` doesn't make the folder and file, do `cd /etc/nginx` then `mkdir sites-available`

Comment: Oh and also do `mkdir sites-enabled` under nginx folder if it is not there